# Does Scala Spark implement map reduce in all cases for running tasks in parallel?

Tags: scala, mapreduce, apache-spark

In order to better understand performance tuning of Spark jobs I'm assuming methods like `groupByKey`, `map` , `flatMap` , `cartesian` are utilizing the map reduce design pattern under the hood.

Reason I'm asking is to better understand how Spark works and therefore write Spark Scala code which runs with higher performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark classifies operations on RDD's into two main categories: Transformations and Actions.

- Transformations: Transform a distributed data structure into another.
  Transformations include operations like: map, flatmap, filter, groupByKey. For the complete list see [spark transformation functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/scala-programming-guide.html#transformations)
- Actions: Actions force collection of values and return results to the job driver.

All transformation functions are lazy and will be executed in a distributed fashion across the spark workers when the value they hold is required. The directed acyclic graph (DAG) formed by the chaining of transformations is called the 'lineage' of a given RDD.
Actions will funnel data from the distributed RDD (on workers) to the driver.

In a nutshell, yes, they follow a distributed computation model alike map-reduce, with two main differences: (1) transformations are lazy: not computed until needed and (2) reusability: transformed data in the form of RDD's (Resilient distributed datasets) can be re-used to further map or reduce transformations.

For an in-depth understanding on how the distributed computing model of Spark works, I recommend you to read the paper: [Resilient Distributed Datasets: A Fault-Tolerant Abstraction for In-Memory Cluster Computing](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/nsdi12/nsdi12-final138.pdf)