# Scala Spark Independent Stages are not running in Parallel

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am looking into a job of Spark. From DAG in spark UI, there are 4 stages in the app, and the first 3 stages are independent. At the end, stage 3 will use the output from stage(0, 1, 2).

```
0  1  2
\  |  /
 \ | /
   3
```

I was thinking stage(0, 1, 2) could run in parallel and stage(3) would run after all stage(0, 1, 2) completed. However, stage(0, 1, 2) are not running in parallel, although they were submitted at the same time. Also, from spark UI, I noticed stage(0, 1, 2) were in active at the same time, when stage(3) was in pending at that time. It looks like 1 is waiting for 0 to be done before starting, and the same for 2 as waiting for 1.

Below is partial code for running this job.

```
def runJob(ss: SparkSession): Unit = {
  (records _)
    .andThen(convertToOtherFormat)
    .andThen(writeRecords(_, path))
}

def records: Dataset[Record] = {
  import sparkSession.implicits._
  region.cityIds              # Set[cityId]
    .map(getContentDataframe) # Set[sql.DataFrame]
    .reduce(_ union _)        # sql.DataFrame 
    .coalesce(numPartitions)  # Dataset[Row]
    .as[Record]               # Dataset[Record]

def convertToOtherFormat(records: Dataset[_ <: Record]): RDD[(Key, Value)] = {
  records # From DAG, this line is shown at the beginning of stage(0, 1, 2)
    .rdd 
    .map(record => {
      add(record)
      (
        new Key(record.key),
        new Value(record.value)
        )
      })
}
```

I have 3 thoughts for this scenario.

1. I thought `records` brought stages(0, 1, 2). Therefore, I tried to add `.par` after `cityIds`, but it has no effect on stages running. By referring some resources, I think if I should create a separate thread for other stages, but it looks like `par` does not need that.
2. It is related with executors I used in this app.
3. Or, I might look in the wrong way, and `records`does not bring stage(0, 1, 2) but something else does.

I am new to both Scala and Spark, and I appreciate some suggestions and resources.
Thanks!

Comment: Don't create threads, Spark is here to handle everything for you!

Comment: Could you provide the whole code as to what `region.cityIds` is?

Answer (score 1):

Only independent Spark jobs are executed in parallel, unless there is a shuffling required - or - when the input of one stage is dependent on the output of another stage.

Spark classifies operations on RDD's in [2 categories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23873816/2205089): transformations and actions.

- Transformations - "transform" between from one distributed data structure into another. This include operations like: `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, `groupByKey`, etc.
- Actions - collect values and return results to the job driver.

In your example, `map` is a transformation, and since transformations are lazy, it will be executed when the code reaches the `reduce` operation. `Reduce`, on the other hand, is an action, and it requires the whole input from the previous stage to finish in order to start. `Map` does run in parallel, but the `reduce` stage is dependent on the previous stage, so it needs serial execution.

`Coalesce` is also a [Spark transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45986604/2205089) which requires `reduce` to finish before it can decrease the number of partitions in an efficient way.
So your stages are not independent of each other.

Assuming `cityIds` is your collection, you can try to create it in a parallel way, like:

`val rdd = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(region.cityIds)`

And then add your stages, but they will still be dependent on each other.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. This is helpful! In my app, I only have one job. From the DAG, I have 3 independent stages (0, 1, 2), but these 3 stages finally get combined together in stage 4. From what I understand so far, they are not fully independent since stage 4 needs all of them. Thus, these 3 stages could not be executed in parallel. Does this sound correct? Thank you again!

Comment: You can edit your question and add a picture with your DAG visualization; it could be that your 3 stages are not independent of one another, otherwise if only stage 4 depends on them I don't see any reason why they should not run in parallel.

Comment: I don't think `map` and `reduce` in the OP's code are Spark operations. `cityIds` is some sort of a Scala collection, probably a collection of strings. `map` is applying `getContentDataframe` and turning it into a collection of datasets. `reduce(_ union _)` is creating a union of those Spark datasets and the first `Dataset` method is the `coalesce` call.

Comment: You might be right, I've been looking at it the wrong way, since I didn't see the rest of the code and have no idea whatsoever what `cityIds` and  `getContentDataframe` are, so I assumed they are are DataFrames, because they have the `union` which is inside the `reduce`.

Comment: ```cityIds``` is a set. Hristo's statement is correct. I thought that was Spark operation but it was map from Scala. Based on this, I am kind of confused which method / step brings in stage (0, 1, 2). I saw ```records.rdd``` in ```convertToOtherFormat ``` was used 3 times in the DAG, so I was thinking it was because of ```records ```. I updated my question. Thanks for your help again!